# Scrapy: cycle results in variables not updating

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, cycle

Here's the part of code that I want to run 4 times. Without counters it works as intended: link to next page is retrieved and scraped for relevant data:

```
def parse_commits_page(self, response):
    yield {
        'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
        'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
        'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
    }
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract()
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_commits_page)
```

Here are the variants of the cycle I tried:

Adding a simple global counter:

```
count = 0
def parse_commits_page(self, response):
    global count
    while (count < 4):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }
        count = count + 1
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract()
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_commits_page)
```

Adding a sub-function:

```
def parse_commits_page(self, response):
    def grabber( response ):
        return {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }

    yield grabber( response )

    for i in range(3):
        yield response.follow(
            response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract(),
            callback=grabber
        )
```

In case of counter the response value is updated either once (if placed as in this code) or not at all if `count = count + 1` is placed at the end.

In case of sub function response is updated only on the last iteration, resulting in 2 scraped pages instead of 4.

**What is the correct way to implement the cycle so that variables are updated as intended?**

Here's complete code if that helps(I use 4 defs instead of a cycle right now):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from random import randint
from time import sleep

BASE_URL = 'https://github.com'

class DiscoverSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'discover_commits_new'
    allowed_domains = ['github.com']
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stars%3E100&ref=simplesearch']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Select all the project urls on page
        project = BASE_URL + response.xpath('//h3/a[@class="v-align-middle"]/@href').extract_first()
        yield response.follow(project, self.parse_project)
        # Random wait, so GitHub doesn't ban me right away
        sleep(randint(5,20))

        # Follow to the next page when every project on this one is scraped
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = BASE_URL + next_page
:           yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # Parse the main page of the project
    def parse_project(self, response):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'tags': [x.strip() for x in response.css('.topic-tag::text').extract()],
            'lang_name': response.css('.lang::text').extract(),
            'lang_perc' : response.css('.percent::text').extract(),
            'stars': response.css('.social-count::text').extract()[1].strip(),
            'forks': response.css('.social-count::text').extract()[2].strip(),
            'commits': response.css('.text-emphasized::text').extract()[0].strip(),
            'contributors': response.css('.text-emphasized::text').extract()[3].strip()
        }

        commits_page = BASE_URL + response.xpath('//*[@class="commits"]//@href').extract_first()
        yield response.follow(commits_page, self.parse_commits_page)

    # Get last commits
    def parse_commits_page(self, response):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract()
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_commits_page1)

    def parse_commits_page1(self, response):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract()
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_commits_page2)

    def parse_commits_page2(self, response):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow"]/@href')[-1].extract()
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_commits_page3)

    def parse_commits_page3(self, response):
        yield {
            'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
            'name': response.xpath('//strong/a/text()').extract(),
            'last_commits': response.xpath('//relative-time/text()').extract()
        }
```